# Blending mode behaves differently on a group?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

Why is the blending behavior different on a group?

Layer vivid light blend over colored layer.

[image]

Exaxt same layer inside a group with vivid light blend.

[image]

And is there any way to get the below effect with just a layer? I tried replicating the effect in HTML/CSS but it showed up as the above image but I did not about this behavior inside Photoshop so I thought CSS was bugging out. I'd like to understand this behavior in Photoshop so I can either mimic this properly in CSS or ask a proper question at SO.

Comment: What is the blend mode of the group? And what are your layers

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. For me in PS CC 2017, "vivid light" works the same whether it's used on a layer, or a group containing a layer. [See screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/BHKI7)

Comment: Can't replicate this either. Must be your specific document.